# How to prove $3^{n-1}>n^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

I am trying to prove using induction $$3^{n-1}>n^2.$$

---

Doing it like proving for $n+1$, it looks like $$3^n>(n+1)^2.$$

If I put it in one side and open brackets and I got 
$$
4\cdot 3^n-2n-1>0.$$

What should be the next step?

Comment: $3n^2\geq n^2+2n+1$ for $n\geq 2$

Comment: What is your base value of $n$? We need at least $n\geq 4$ for this to be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is $$3^{n-1}>n^2$$

Then $$3^{n}-(n+1)^2 = 3^n-n^2-2n-1=\underbrace{(3^{n-1}-n^2)}_{> 0\quad\text{by our assumption}}+2\cdot3^{n-1}-2n-1$$

Then we can prove the statement true for $n+1$ by showing that $$2\cdot 3^{n-1}-2n-1 > 0$$

This is easily done by induction for $n\geq 2$, $n=2$ is true, then we assume true for $n$.

Now $$2\cdot 3^n-2(n+1)-1 = 6\cdot3^{n-1}-2n-3=(2\cdot3^{n-1}-2n-1)+(5\cdot3^{n-1}-2)>0$$

And we're done.

Answer (score 0):

For $n> 3$, $n^2>2n$ and $n^2>1$. Further,
$$3^n=3^{n-1}+3^{n-1}+3^{n-1}>n^2+n^2+n^2>n^2+2n+1=(n+1)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the inductive assumption as follows:
$$
3^n = 3 \cdot 3^{n-1} > 3n^2 \geq (n+1)^2
$$
the last inequality being true for any $n \geq 2$.

Answer (score 0):

The point with induction is that you assume that it is true for $n$, and then use that assumption to prove that it is true for $n+1$. I'm going to assume that you want to prove it for $n\geq4$, since the statement is true for $n=4$, but not for smaller $n$.

So in this case you assume that for $n$ we have that $3^{n-1}>n^2$. Multiplying this by $3$, you get $3^n>3n^2=n^2+2n^2$. Now, for $n\geq4$, we have that $2n^2\geq2n+1$, which means that $3^n>n^2+2n+1=(n+1)^2$. Which completes the proof.